# If I have $m \times n$ matrix A and a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$, Can I make Ax working? Will it be possible for Ax to do row operations?

Tags: matrices, vectors

If I have $m \times n$ matrix A and a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$，where m>n, Can I make Ax working? Will it be possible for Ax to do row operations? If yes, then how do they operate?

Answer (score 3):

No.  If $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix and x is an $m$-vector ($m \times 1$ matrix), then $Ax$ isn't well defined. 
In general, If A is $m_1 \times n_1$ and B is $m_2 \times n_2$, then $AB$ is well defined only if $n_1=m_2$. 
Even if $x=\textbf{0}_m$ (the $m$-vector w/ all entries 0), $Ax$ isn't well defined. 
If x=0 (the scalar), then $Ax$ is the matrix of all 0's.  But it's customary to put scalars in front of the matrix or vector, as in $xA$.

Comment: What if x is {0}?

Comment: I made an edit to answer your question.